# Visual Studio Code - TypeScript - not showing errors inline when tsconfig.json contains data

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I add an empty .tsconfig file (by empty i mean "{ }") Visual Studio code shows error inline and in the "problems" section. As soon as I add data to the tsconfig.json file, errors are no longer shown there.
Do I need to set some specific setting that's set on default but not when you edit the tsconfig.json?

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "checkJs": true,
    },
    "files": [
        "./node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts",
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I already tried to remove "module": "commonjs" from the file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394831/visual-studio-code-intellisense-typescript-not-working) but this didn't work for me.

Comment: Remove `files`, wrong usage there and the typings are checked automatically in `@types`

Comment: @Marv I removed `files` but the errors are still not highlighted.

Comment: try renaming to `tsconfig.json`, might be the default one vscode looks for. And whenever doing a change, reload the vscode window

Comment: The file is already named `tsconfig.json`. Reloading after a change doesn't seem to help me either.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the tsconfig.json and came up with the following:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I am not sure why, but this solved my problem.

Comment: In a similar situation, changing `"target":` from `"es5"` to `"es6"` helped. Of course that wasn't the case here, your original config already had `"target": "es6"`.