# Intellisense for angular in Vs code does not work

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using Vs Code for Angular project.
Yesterday when I typed something like "ng...", It showed the Intellisence for *ngFor,*ngIf,*ngModel ..... Today it is not anymore. Can some one help me please. 
Sorry for inconvinience, I can not post the picture right now.

Comment: Can you press ctrl + space to elaborate more options?

Comment: just `disable` the extension  and  `enable` it again from the installed extension list

Comment: It does not work sir :(

Comment: Probably due to TSLint extension related vs code configuration, may be anyone else who will face same issue could try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228384/tslint-extension-throwing-errors-in-my-angular-application-running-in-visual-stu

Comment: Adding to above comment, this may also help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394831/visual-studio-code-intellisense-typescript-not-working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VS CODE does not have those by default, you need to install the [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) if you want to have that. Probably you might have uninstalled or restored VSCode. Try to install it and see again.

Comment: I have done nothing to Vs Code since yesterday. I have no idea why this happen. And properly I  do have installed some Extension. Should I uninstall those extensions and install your recommended Extension?

Comment: yeah try and see

Answer (score 6):

Reinstalling [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) works for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you press ctrl + space to elaborate more options? also please check you have installed Angular Snippets in VsCode Extension. Or restart your vscode maybe it works.

Comment: ctrl+space does not work. It shows no suggestion :(. I have try to restart VS code too, does not work either

Comment: use Cmd+I on a Mac