# TSLint extension throwing errors in my Angular application running in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

I recently started seeing, what seems like, [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) errors.
They look like this:

> Not using the local TSLint version found for
> '/Users/myname/myproject/client/src/app/likes/likee/likee.component.ts'.
> To enable code execution from the current workspace you must enable workspace library execution.

I'm seeing them in my .ts files when I open them and it shows a yellow squiggly line on the first line of each .ts page.

I see on the [TSLint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) site it says it's been deprecated.

What's the cause of these errors and why am I suddenly seeing them?

Should I uninstall the Visual Studio Code TSLint extension and install the [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint) extension?

Answer (score 472):

Like [Tuấn Nguyễn described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230524/11471113), you need to:

1. Go to the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>,
2. In the input that pops up at the top of the Visual Studio Code, start typing

   ```
   TSLint: Manage workspace library execution"
   ```

   and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
3. From the menu that replaces the input, pick *enable workspace library execution* and again press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Is there any way to make this change "sticky"? Enabling workspace library execution works, but it seems when I close VS Code and re-open the same project, I have to enable it again.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett From the same menu choose "Always enable workspace library execution"

Comment: Yes, this solution worked fine for me by having my ecosystem (visual code, angular, etc.)  up to the day.

Comment: After vscode restart, it shows again. Downvoting.

Answer (score 85):

You should go to the *[Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-palette)* in Visual Studio Code to search for TSLint: Manage workspace library execution. And enable workspace library execution.

Comment: @user1186050 ctrl + shift + p > TSLint: Manage workspace library execution > Enter > Enable workspace library execution

Comment: After vscode restart, it shows again. Downvoting.

Answer (score 51):

Although [the answer given by @Tuấn Nguyễn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228384/tslint-extension-throwing-errors-in-my-angular-application-running-in-visual-stu/65230524#65230524) works, yet it is not advisable to do so.

As per Microsoft documentation,
*[TSLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin)*, this answer will replace the global TSLint configuration defined with the local one, which one can manipulate easily and it’s not recommended due to security reasons as well.

**Screenshot:**

> [image]

**Recommended Approach:**

As per Microsoft documentation, *[Migrate from TSLint to ESLint](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration)*,  updated recently (2020-12-11), you should migrate from TSLint to ESLint.

*This might be the reason that everyone is looking for the fix, as needful things were done by Microsoft recently. :)*

**Steps:**

1. `npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`  (Install ESLint and TSLint)
2. `npx tslint-to-eslint-config` (This will install a utility tool and make configuration easier. Post install, a new **.eslintrc.js** will be created. There will be changes to **.vscode/settings.json** as well.)
3. Disable/Uninstall TSLint from your Visual Studio Code.
4. You can then, place a script in your **package.json** file as - `"lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext .ts <mySrcFolder>"`. (This will tell ESLint to look for TSLint)

But, you should probably look once, over steps in **link** more vividly, in order to follow the steps correctly and accordingly.

Comment: when I am doing step 2 I get this error :npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "eshghi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\16104" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: I already have a line
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
should I add your step 4. as
"eslint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext .ts src",
? these script are manually invoked by user (me) via npm run eslint ? or are they keywords expected by serve and build scripts?  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I will note that if you're using a framework like Angular, which provides a separate TSLint to ESLint conversion tool (like they do), you should use the framework's tool and, unless specified, do NOT use this method, as it will break your ESLint config file and you will get MASSIVE errors. If I had known this ahead of time, I would have saved countless hours.

Answer (score 44):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

In the input that pops up at the top of the Visual Studio Code, write

```
TSLint: Manage workspace library execution
```

From the menu that replaces the input, pick

```
Enable Workspace Library Execution
```

Comment: After vscode restart, it shows again. Downvoting.

Answer (score 35):

Go to [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>,

In the input that pops up at the top of Visual Studio Code, start typing

TSLint: Manage workspace library execution"
and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

From the menu that replaces the input, pick enable workspace library execution, and again hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: After vscode restart, it shows again. Downvoting.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed the issue in this easy way:

Menu *File* → *Save Workspace As...*

By saving the workspace, Visual Studio Code detects some libraries and works better in files.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the TSLint Manage Workspace on the Command Palette as others suggested, but after saving the workspace it appeared and worked just fine!

Comment: @Lauro your welcome, i am happy for fix this

Comment: Thanks. You inspired me. Just reboot the editor solved my problem.

Comment: waww!! Thank you a lot !! I had a problem with ngModel directive whereas i imported FormsModule but I couldn't delete this error : "There is no directive with exportAs set to ngForm".  You help me by this way.

Answer (score 13):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Windows or Linux or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac
2. Type *TSLint: Manage workspace library execution*

   [image: TSLint: Manage workspace library execution]
3. Choose *Always enable workspace library execution*

   [image: Always enable workspace library execution]

   Or you can save workspace file => *Save workspace as*

   [image: Save workspace]

Answer (score 2):

The second question: Yes, you should uninstall TSLint and migrate to ESLint since TSLint has been deprecated from Microsoft. [This link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration) might help you.

Comment: Just to clarify and be overly explicit - despite the fact that Angular uses **Type**Script, we no longer are supposed to use **TS**Lint but rather **ES**Lint, even if we code not using **Ecma**Script. Is that correctly understood?

Comment: Yes exactly. Just follow the  [migration guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration) and basically everything will work as before, but with ESLint instead of TSLint

Answer (score 0):

Jump to the error. Hover over the lightbulb and you will see the option. Click it and you must be getting the prompt to allow it.

This is how I fixed it myself recently.

*[VS Code ESLint extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint)* has a more detailed guide. There are multiple steps on how to do it (including the other answers here).

This probably is a security thing from Visual Studio Code to prevent bad things from happening in your code.

Comment: Images are overused, but this is a case where it would be a benefit.

Answer (score -4):

1. install TypeScript globally
2. Try to configure your IDE
3. execute: `npm i typescript -g`

Comment: A properly configured Visual Studio Code should work without a global TypeScript installation.