# Angular - How to import Javascript into Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular-11, I have this Javascript file:

> "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bs-stepper/js/bs-stepper.min.js",

I added it to angular.json as shown above.

```js
import Stepper from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  private stepper: Stepper;

  next() {
    this.stepper.next();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    return false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stepper = new Stepper(document.querySelector('#stepper1'), {
      linear: false,
      animation: true
    })
  }
}
```

How do I import it into this component: profile.component.ts this way,

import Stepper from '...';

from the Javascript path

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `import Stepper from 'bs-stepper';` ?

Comment: @RomanA - When I did import Stepper from 'bs-stepper'; it didn't recognise Stepper. So, I am using AdminLTE3 which has it's own helper

Comment: import * as Stepper from 'node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bs-stepper/js/bs-stepper.min.js;' 
or  import Stepper from 'node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bs-stepper/js/bs-stepper.min.js;' 
Have you tried this?

Comment: @RomanA. - I got this error:   ot using the local TSLint version found for 'c:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/src/app/auth/profile/profile.component.ts'
To enable code execution from the current workspace you must enable workspace library execution.tslint(1)

Comment: Plz check this for your latest issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228384/tslint-extension-throwing-errors-in-my-angular-application-running-in-visual-stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens there is a NPM package for [`bs-stepper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-stepper) that could be used out-of-the-box with Angular.

#### 1. Install the package

From the project root folder, run the command

```
npm install bs-stepper --save
```

Also install `bootstrap` if needed

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

#### 2. Import the CSS

**styles.css**

```css
@import '~bs-stepper/dist/css/bs-stepper.min.css';

/* Also import bootstrap if needed */
@import '~bs-stepper/dist/css/bs-stepper.min.css';
```

#### 3. Use `ViewChild` instead of `querySelector`

Using `document.querySelector` in an Angular app would search the entire DOM whereas the element would only be present in the current component. Based on the size of the app it might incur a performance issue. Instead you could use the `@ViewChild` decorator with with a template reference variable

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<!-- Here, `bsStepper` is the template reference variable -->

<div #bsStepper id="stepper1" class="bs-stepper">
  ...
</div>
```

**Component (*.ts)**

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import Stepper from 'bs-stepper';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('bsStepper', { static: false }) stepperElement!: ElementRef<any>;
  public stepper!: Stepper;

  next() {
    this.stepper.next();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    return false;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.stepper = new Stepper(this.stepperElement.nativeElement, {
      linear: false,
      animation: true
    });
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular-o6rx4o?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Everything was looking good until when I got this error in the component.ts:    Property 'stepperElement' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Property 'stepper' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Comment: @user11352561: It has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc#comment115216132_49699097). Quick fix is to tell the TS compiler explicitly about the property: `public stepper!: Stepper;`. Note the exclamation mark in the declaration. Do it also for the `@ViewChild` property is required. I've adjusted the answer and the Stackblitz.

Answer (score 2):

You must first declare it in typing.d.ts and include angular.json script.

**in angular.json**

```
{
  "build" : {
      "scripts" : [
           "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bs-stepper/js/bs-stepper.min.js",
           ....
       ]
```

**in typing.d.ts**

```
declare module 'admin-lte/plugins/bs-stepper/js/bs-stepper.min';
```

**Note :** If this is a JQuery package then you need to create an interface.

```
declare module 'jquery';
interface JQuery { 
  Stepper(DOM : any, options?: any): any;
}
```

finally you can now call it in the component.

**in component**

```
import Stepper from 'admin-lte/plugins/bs-stepper/js/bs-stepper.min';
```

**Edit :** Create a file named `typing.d.ts` inside the src folder. then add

```
/// <reference path = "typings.d.ts" />
```

to the top of the `src/main.ts` file

Comment: where is in typing.d.ts located? Thanks