# How can I fix error TS5023 throwed by adding "allowImportingTsExtensions" in tsconfig.json file?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

While building or running my React project I encounter the following error:

> Could not parse tsconfig.json. Please make sure it contains syntactically correct JSON.
> Details: error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'allowImportingTsExtensions'.

I did some research on the possible cause of the error but those couldn't help me:

For context:

- I made sure of including in my **tsconfig.json** file the option **"noEmit": true**;
- I've tried to add another option that now I can't remember;
- Excluding **"allowImportingTsExtensions"** isn't even possible because I need it in the project.

The following snippet represents my **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Can anybody help me fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct `tsc` version?

Comment: Sounds like you're using a version of `tsc` < 5. The option was added in v5: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#allowimportingtsextensions

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't install any tsc version and as suggested I installed tsc Version 5.0.4.  Unfortunately this didn't fix my problem.

Comment: @PaoloMura - You won't get that error from v5.0.4, so I suspect you have multiple copies installed (easier to do than you might thing) and are getting the wrong one. That's what I'd suggest focusing on when trying to debug this. (FWIW, I just created a new project, copied your `tsconfig.json` above into it, added a file, and compiled without trouble using v5.0.4. I downgraded to v4.9.5 and got the error you describe.)

Comment: I mean: Make sure you're using the right version of `tsc`. For instance, if you have `"build": "tsc"` in your `"scripts"` in `package.json` and you're getting the error above from `npm run build` (or similar), change it to `"build": "tsc --version"`and run it. That will tell you the version that's getting picked up by that command. Given the test I did above showing that your `tsconfig.json` is absolutely fine with v5.0.4, I can only conclude you'll see a lower version.

Comment: Oh nice, you know if there are some guide that can help me uninstall previous versions (if this is the final solution)?

Comment: I don't know of anything specific. First I'd uninstall it globally (`npm uninstall -g typescript` if you're using `npm`), then from the project (I'm sure you know this, but just for clarity: `npm uninstall typescript` if you're using `npm`), then install it to the project (again, not trying to talk down, just for clarity: `npm install -D typescript`). Then the right version should get picked up by a build script such as the above. Good hunting! :-)

Comment: I really appreciate the help you gave me, but I can't give you any points. I hope you can still appreciate my gratitude!

Comment: Very kind of you to say! Points are overrated, I'll take a kind word any day. Happy coding!

Comment: Maybe you can answer the question so I can choose it as accepted answer. Anyway, that answer fixed the error but, obviously, I got another one :D. Classic succession of events while coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get this error when tsc command in the console (and in the build script) does not have the same version as what you have in VSCode.

to fix it remove the global TypeScript :

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

the nand reinstall it again  :

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Answer (score 2):

For others bumping into this because their IDE complains (not because the project doesn't build), it's possible that your IDE doesn't use the same TypeScript version as the one you've installed in your project. That was the case for me. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Open the VS Code command palette with Ctrl + Shift + P (on Windows)
2. Find "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version…"
3. Choose "Use Workspace Version"

In my case, the workspace version was `5.3.3`, while the VS Code version was `4.9.5`, so it made sense to receive this error — the feature does not exist on this version.

For more info, including screenshots, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57005562/3130281).